# Create a persistent mapping for a apppool identity

Tags: iis-7.5, mapped-drive, mvc

Can I create a persistent mapping for a apppool identity?

For instance the IIS website "www.example.net" should access "\10.10.10.222\shared$" through F:

My Website is MVC(5) so I think the Application Pool requires Integrated Mode.

Answer (score 0):

This question is not belong to here, that's why you can't get an answer. 
I suggest you make it on http://serverfault.com

I can't flag/move it because it has a bounty.